# Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined at isNamedImportBindings

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi I encountered the error below while I am trying to run

```
ionic cordova build browser --configuration=production
```

where I have my production configuration in angular.json as below

```
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "6mb",
                  "maximumError": "6mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

and I got a tons of red line error as below

```
ERROR in : TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isNamedImportBindings (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:14088:25)
    at Object.Debug.assertNode (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:63135:90)
    at visitNode (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62219:18)
    at visitEachChild (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62535:100)
    at visitor (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/make_transform.js:66:28)
    at visitNode (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62205:23)
    at visitEachChild (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62533:167)
    at visitor (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/make_transform.js:66:28)
    at visitNodes (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62256:48)
    at visitLexicalEnvironment (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62289:22)
    at visitEachChild (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62593:54)
    at visitor (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/make_transform.js:66:28)
    at Object.visitNode (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62205:23)
    at transformer (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/make_transform.js:73:31)
    at /home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1354:86
    at reduceLeft (/home/mph-ddc/workspace/mph/ddc-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1066:30)
```

I could find a lot of results from googling related to this error message but really was not able to find any of them occured this error at the line **isNamedImportBindings**.

Below is my ionic info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/home/mph-ddc/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.10
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.10
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : browser 6.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 26 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/mph-ddc/android-sdk-linux)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.0 (/home/mph-ddc/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Linux 4.14
```

Hope anyone would give me some help.

Thanks.

Comment: can u delete `package-lock.json` and do `npm i` once. Let me know if that worked

Comment: Hi @ShashankVivek, I tried your approach but it doesn't seem working.